# Serializing into dictionary Stored Procedure result using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, stored-procedures, flask, sqlalchemy, cursor

I am having stored procedure in mysql database and the use sqlalchemy to fetch result.

```
    connection = db.engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('catalog_get_products_on_catalog', [2000, 10, 0])
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(results)
```

I get result as tuple:

```
(10, 'abcd')
```

For normal sqlalchemy result marshmallow can be used to serialize the result into dictionary, is it possible to convert the tuple into dictionary by defining a schema in marshmallow?

Answer (score 0):

Marshmallow currently doesn't seem to have that functionality, The following alternative works:

```
data = db.session.execute(sqlalchemy.text("CALL catalog_get_products_on_catalog(:inShortProductDescriptionLength, :inProductsPerPage, :inStartItem)"),
                                 {'inShortProductDescriptionLength':20, 'inProductsPerPage':10, 'inStartItem':0}).fetchall()

results = []
for row_number, row in enumerate(data):
    results.append({})
    for column_number, value in enumerate(row):
        results[row_number][row.keys()[column_number]] = value
```

**UPDATE :** 
It can be done simply by,

`results = [dict(row) for row in data]`

Or

`results = [*map(dict,data)]`

Comment: Or you could just say `results = [dict(row) for row in data]`.

Comment: or `results = [*map(dict, data)]`